# The inhabitants of Heaven will express love intimately through the use of their sex organs?

Tags: heaven, eschatology, sexuality

I have often wondered on our relationships in the New Earth, after resurrection.

Men and women will enjoy each another in a physical sense? will we still have "sexual feelings", And sexual pleasure in Heaven?

If we look at the paradise lost, it gives you some inkling what paradise restored will be like.  In paradise lost there were flesh and sex, there were trees, it was a physical place. Paradise restored will be this universe minus death, disease, decay, and destruction.
Personally, I do not see any reason why there would not be a physical dimension to a gender based spiritual relationship. God made us male and female for eternity and for some reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will there be "new people" or reproduction in heaven or "the next life?"](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5024/will-there-be-new-people-or-reproduction-in-heaven-or-the-next-life)

Comment: Actually, a better duplicate here: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/20060/can-humans-fall-in-love-with-each-other-in-heaven/20065#20065

Comment: This is a truth question. Probably most Christians do reason as brusied reed does below, but not all do.

Comment: The Bible never mentions it (Rather we have Matthew 22:30 as in the answer below). Whereas the Koran is full of carnal speech about paradise. By analogy, its obviously not the view in Christianity, since if it was, surely it would be mentioned *at least once*, like the 100s of references to such an idea in the Koran.

Answer (score 6):

The strong implication of [Matthew 22:30](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matt%2022%3A30&version=NKJV)* -

> For in the resurrection they neither marry nor are given in marriage, but are like angels of God in heaven. - NKJV

Is that **no they won't**.

*Given the overall context of what scripture says elsewhere about sex and marriage.